# nginx - serving backend and frontend on different endpoints and same domain

Tags: angularjs, laravel, nginx, frontend, backend

I have installed **nginx** on OS X with **php7.1**, **mysql** and so on... and the basic testing example is working.

When I try to configure nginx to serve **Laravel backend** on `user.domain.dev/api/...` and **Angular frontend** on `user.domain.dev/...` I am getting **404** or **403**. Nginx error log is mostly

```
/Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/api.domain.dev/" is forbidden
```

or

```
/Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/frontend.domain.dev/build/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I can't seem to understand nginx's location directive and so they're pointing to a wrong directories. Thanks for any advices or guidance.

My config is:

**nginx.conf**

```
user name staff;  
worker_processes auto;

events {  
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {  
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_certificate ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/nginx.key;

    access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    gzip  on;

    include servers/*.conf;
}
```

**servers/domain.dev.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name domain.dev *.domain.dev www.domain.dev;

    charset utf-8;

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)

    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www

    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    ##
    ## Backend HTTP server
    ##

    location /api {

        root /Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/api.domain.dev;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi.conf;
            }
    }

    ##
    ## Frontend HTTP server
    ##

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { 
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt  { 
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off; 
    }

    location / {
        root /Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/frontend.domain.dev/build;
        index index.html;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `staff` user have access to the directories specified in the `root` directives? If not, that will explain the 403 error. For your `index.php` file that can't be found, you haven't specified it in your `index` directive. You only have `index.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is an inconsistent use of the `root` directive. You have two document roots, one for each application, but only specified in two of your locations. There is no `root` specified at the `server { ... }` block level, therefore `if (!-d $request_filename)` is meaningless, `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$` will always result in a `404` response, etc.

Read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) to understand how `nginx` processes a request.

But you should probably set the frontend root in the `server` block and override it with the backend root in the `location /api` block.

```
server {
    root /Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/frontend.domain.dev/build;

    location / { ... }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ { ... }

    location ^~ /api {
        root /Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/api.domain.dev;
        ...
    }
}
```

This would place the backend document root at: `/Users/name/Projects/domain.dev/api.domain.dev/api` -- note that the URI is always appended to the `root`.

Note also, the `^~` modifier is used to make the prefix location take precedence over regular expression locations at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

I do not like the naked `if` blocks in your design. The `if (!-d $request_filename)` should probably be replaced with a [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), and `if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))` should probably be replaced by using a separate `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

The `try_files` statement in your `location /api` block contains an incorrect default URI, it should probably be `/api/index.php?$query_string`.